# Ubuntu server 15 during ping (DUP!) what does it mean

Tags: ubuntu, ping

For some time during ping 192.168.0.2 I have something like this `(DUP!)` something is wrong with my network card or switch?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LndPH.jpg)

Ubuntu server 15 - `*192.168.0.222*`
Windows server 2012 - `*192.168.0.2*` - Virtual machine

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.369 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.203 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.280 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.343 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.443 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=0.306 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=0.393 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=0.283 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=0.380 ms (DUP!)

wlodek@ubuntu:/etc/network$ cat interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0 

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0


    #Interface
    auto bond0

    iface bond0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.222
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.100
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8

    bond-mode 6
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves none
```

ping from `192.168.0.79`(Ubuntu server 15 (Samba)) to `192.168.0.2` Windows serevr 2012 **no DUP!**

*`192.168.0.79`*

```
wlodek@Samba:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:4d:25:11:c7  
          inet addr:192.168.0.79  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:4dff:fe25:11c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4303692 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2829493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6299362962 (6.2 GB)  TX bytes:502897264 (502.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1200613 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1200613 (1.2 MB)

64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.589 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.346 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.376 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.319 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=0.379 ms
```

Comment: You have two machines answering to your request. Do you have the same error if you ping another IP ?

Comment: only if I ping 192.168.0.2 from Ubunto server to Windows server 2012 - I forgot to add this. Ubuntu serevr is `192.168.0.222`, Windows server is `192.168.0.2` - Virtual machine

Comment: Can you check "Routing and Remote Access" and "Internet connection Sharing on the Windows" - it has been reported that when enabled on a virtual server duplicate ping replies might occur? Also you can try capturing the traffic with tcpdump or wireshark to check where the duplicate ping replies comes from.